# scikit-learn HashingVectorizer on sparse matrix

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

In scikit-learn, how can I run the HashingVectorizer on data already present in a scipy.sparse matrix?

My data is in svmlight format, so I am loading it with sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file and get a scipy.sparse matrix to work on.

The [TfidfTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer) from scikit-learn can be fed such a sparse matrix to transform it, but how can I give the same sparse matrix to the [HashingVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer) to use it instead?

EDIT:
Is there maybe a series of method calls that can be used on the sparse matrix, maybe using the [FeatureHasher](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher)?

EDIT 2: After a useful discussion with the user cfh below, the goal I have is to go from input: a sparse count matrix gotten from svmlight data to output: a matrix of token occurrences, such as the HashingVectorizer is giving. How could this be done?

I provided a sample code below and would really appreciate some help on how to do that, thanks in advance:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# example data
X_train = np.array([[1., 1.], [2., 3.], [4., 0.]])
print "X_train: \n", X_train
# transform to scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix to be consistent with output from load_svmlight_file
X_train_crs = csr_matrix(X_train)
print "X_train_crs: \n", X_train_crs   
# no problem to run TfidfTransformer() on this csr matrix to get a transformed csr matrix
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(X_train)
print "tfidf: \n", tfidf
# How do I use the HashingVectorizer with X_train_crs ?
hv = HashingVectorizer(n_features=2)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. The `HashingVectorizer` computes a document-term matrix, just the kind of matrix that you can feed into the `TfidfTransformer`. Why would you want to hash such a matrix again?

Comment: The `TfidfTransformer` "transforms a count matrix to a normalized tf or tf-idf representation". I have a count matrix, but I need the hashing trick applied on it. The `HashingVectorizer` "converts a collection of text documents to a matrix of token occurrences". So my goal is: Input:  count matrix and output: hashed matrix of token occurrences.

Comment: I don't think that's how the hashing trick works, you're supposed to hash the words already during parsing instead of building a dictionary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing#Feature_vectorization_using_the_hashing_trick

Comment: In other words, the `HashingVectorizer` already implements the hashing trick.

Comment: The data I have is in svmlight format. The only way I see it currently might work is to read in the svmlight data, write it out again in text files and then read it in again via the ``HashingVectorizer``, but this seems awfully inefficient. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How large is your matrix?

Comment: Classification, the data is quite similar as this data: [libsvmdata](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multilabel.html#rcv1v2%20%28industries;%20full%20sets%29) but has over 1 million features and it is sparse. I use LinearSVC and really want to explore feature hashing as a dimensionality reduction possibility for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashing basically combines words randomly into a smaller number of buckets. With an already computed frequency matrix, you can emulate this like so:

```
n_features = X_train.shape[1]
n_desired_features = n_features / 5
buckets = np.random.random_integers(0, n_desired_features-1, size=n_features)
X_new = np.zeros((X_train.shape[0], n_desired_features), dtype=X_train.dtype)
for i in range(n_features):
    X_new[:,buckets[i]] += X_train[:,i]
```

Of course you can adjust the `n_desired_features` as you wish.
Just make sure to use the same `buckets` for the test data as well.

If you need to do the same for a sparse matrix, you can do this:

```
M = coo_matrix((repeat(1,n_features), (range(n_features), buckets)),
               shape=(n_features,n_desired_features))
X_new = X_train.dot(M)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only if X_train is a numpy.ndarray, but not if is a sparse csr matrix, which is required, given millions of features in the input data.

Comment: @tkja: But you can easily set up a sparse matrix of size `n_features x n_desired_features` which, when multiplied with your actual feature matrix, will produce the same effect as what I have sketched in my answer column-by-column.

Comment: @tkja: I've added an example to that effect.

Comment: In the last line, do you mean `X_new = X_train.dot(M)`? Also, `shape=(5,5)` should be, as you earlier said, `shape(n_features x n_desired_features)`? If so, could you reformat it in your answer as a self-contained example? I could then accept it and it could be helpful to others that have similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: @tkja: Sorry, some typos were left over. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Can `M = csr_matrix` be used instead of `M = coo_matrix`? I read the input for some algorithms in scikit is csr matrix, or the output is a csr format (as is the case for my example with the sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file method).

Comment: @tkja: Sure, these are only different storage formats for sparse matrices. Just make sure that the constructor arguments match for both classes.